# Assembly : Returning 64 bits pointer address (nasm unix x64)

Tags: c, pointers, assembly, 64-bit, nasm

I try to reproduce strcat standard c function using asm.

Here's my C test main :

```
char    *ft_strcat(char *s1, const char *s2);

int main(void)
{
    char str1[60];
    str1[0] = 'a';
    str1[1] = '\0';
    char str2[] = "poney";

    printf("\n>> Test de ft_strcat <<\n\n");
    printf("str1 (%p) = \"%s\"\n", str1, str1);
    printf("str2 (%p) = \"%s\"\n", str2, str2);
    printf("ft_strcat(str1, str2) : %p\n", ft_strcat(str1, str2));
    printf("str1 (%p) = \"%s\"\n", str1, str1);
   
    return (0);
}
```

and my assembler code

```
section .text
global _ft_strcat

_ft_strcat:
mov rax, qword rdi    ; save pointer address in rdi to return it later

start:
    cmp [rdi], byte 0
    jz next
    inc rdi
    jmp start

next:
    cmp [rsi], byte 0
    je end
    mov r11, [rsi]
    mov [rdi], r11
    inc rdi
    inc rsi
    jmp next

end:
    mov [rdi], byte 0
    ret                ; return rax
```

And here's the result :

> str1 (0x7fff5fbffb30) = "a"
>
> str2 (0x7fff5fbffb20) = "poney"
>
> ft_strcat(str1, str2) : 0x5fbffb30
>
> str1 (0x7fff5fbffb30) = "aponey"

It appears that the upper 32 bits of my pointer address have disappeared. I can't explain why.

I know it is not just a printf issue because if I try to print string instead of pointer address from ft_strcat return, I get a segfault.

Any idea ?

Comment: ret 8 ; return 8 bytes from rax ? Not at all.

Comment: What calling convention do you intend to use here? Your code seems to no be using a stack frame, and C normally puts its arguments in it.

Comment: yes actually this ret was stupid, I had to remove it. It also made my program segfault several times.

Comment: it is intel x64, I get function parameters thru rdi and rsi and return thru rax

Comment: You are moving 8 bytes in each iteration of the loop. This is inefficient, causes unaligned memory accesses and accesses memory beyond the end of both the source and destination strings.  Use a byte register and test for `0` after the move or use the `movsb` instruction to perform load, store and increment on both `rsi` and `rdi`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok my bad, it is not an asm issue. I solved the problem by adding #include "libfts.h" at top of my main.

Without functions prototypes, I suppose there's no way the program can tell if the function is returning 1 or 8 bytes..

at this line:

mov rax, qword rdi

qword is not needed since move from/to 64bit registers will already copy 8 bytes

I also added compilator flags to my Makefile to prevent this kind of error.

Answer (score 1):

The mistake is here:

```
mov rax, qword rdi    ; save pointer address in rdi to return it later
```

I think this should be:

```
mov rax,rdi   ; save pointer address in rdi to return it later
```

Also I think the main loop should be rewritten like this (not optimal because it goes one character at a time, but given that you increment `rsi` and `rdi` once in each loop, I think that this is what you inteded to do):

```
next:
    cmp byte [rsi],0
    je end
    mov cl,[rsi]  ;load 8 bits
    mov [rdi],cl  ;store 8 bits
    inc rdi
    inc rsi
    jmp next
```

Comment: I added qword to try to force size but I as answered myself, I was a C function prototype problem.

Comment: do you mean my code copy 8 chars every times ? Can it lead to any segfault ?

Comment: @Rox Teddy: accessing memory beyond array bounds definitely invokes undefined behaviour.  If the destination array is not at least 6 bytes longer than the source string, you are overwriting something else in memory.  Even reading memory beyond the end of the string invokes undefined behaviour.

Comment: @mcleod_ideafix: further optimize the code: testing `cl` against `0` *after* copying and incrementing will save 1 memory access and 1 `jmp` from the loop.